# Automapper from SOAP Web Service to View Model

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, soap, automapper

I want to use Automapper for mapping SOAP Web Service Response to a Model which will be used to return the result through a Web API.

Mostly of the attributes returned in the object by the web service are codes, we want to show in the response of our api the descriptions related to those codes.

For example:

The web service response with a list of:

```
<charge>
    <type>ABC</type>
    <qualifier>3</qualifier>
    <periodCode>004</periodCode>
    <code>STE</code>
</charge>
<charge> ... </charge>
```

Which will be encapsulated in a class like this:

```
class Charge {
    string type { get; set; }
    string qualifier { get; set; }
    string periodCode { get; set; }
    string code { get; set; }
    decimal rate { get; set; }
}
```

Our model is:

```
public class RCharge {
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool? IncludedInRate { get; set; }
    public decimal? AmountValue { get; set; }
    public string Period { get; set; }
}
```

I have stored in a database the information related to the codes and descriptions, as all codes have their own description.

The problem is how to map from the code returned in the web service, to the description. I have this code, and I could make a call to the database in search of the code and get the description, but is it ok? I guess the ConstructUsing is executed for every item in the response, so make a query here would result in a bunch of requests to DB.

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(config => {
    config
        .CreateMap<Charge, RCharge>()
        .ConstructUsing(s => RChargeConstructor.Construct(s));
});

public class RChargeConstructor {
    public static RCharge Construct(ResolutionContext context) {
        if (context == null || context.IsSourceValueNull)
            return null;

        var src = (Charge)context.SourceValue;

        return new RCharge() {
            Description = src.type, // want description from DB
            IncludedInRate = src.qualifier == "3",
            AmountValue = src.rate,
            Period = src.periodCode // want description from DB
        };
    }
}
```

Is there a good approach for doing this kind of mapping?

Comment: No. AutoMapper was invented precisely to get rid of all these assignments you have in `new RCharge() { }`. In this case, where source and target property names are different, you better do it without AM.

Comment: Well, I'm stuck here. The example I gave is one part of a larger mapping where I'm including nested, and several other maps, all part of the same process. The particularity with this is the **codes** stuff, where in the other mappings the data come flat and is easily mapped.

Comment: I can only judge this particular case.